On relative numerical properties of a divisor in the total space
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normal complex analytic spaces, and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a surjective morphism with connected fibers (sometimes referred to as a fiber space in some references). Let $D$ be a Cartier divisor on $X$. One can define several relative numerical notions such as $f$ nef, $f$-ample, and $f$-big, based on whether $\left.D\right|_{X_y}$ is nef, ample, or big for any (or general) $y \in Y$.
It is generally understood that for a morphism, one can appropriately pull back a Cartier divisor from the target space when the image of this morphism is sufficiently large (a variation of the concept of 'domination'). However, the inclusion $X_y \rightarrow X$ does not satisfy these types of conditions.

Question: What is the precise definition of $D|_{X_y}$ in
the context of relative numerical notions?

Clues: For instance, assume that the support of a divisor $E$ on $X$ does not intersect with $X_y$. In this case, how should one define $\left.E\right|_{X_y}$ ? Should we modify $E$ within its linear equivalence class so that $E \cap X_y$ intersects properly?

You can always pull-back the line bundle $\mathcal O(D)$ to $X_y$, and the notions nef, ample and big are actually properties of the line bundle, not of the divisor.

@red_trumpet that looks like an answer to me - would you consider recording that below?

You can always pull-back the line bundle $O(D)$ to $X_y$, and the notions nef, ample and big are actually properties of the line bundle, not of the divisor.

In the book Algebraic Varieties: Minimal Models and Finite Generation by Kawamata, translated by Chen Jiang, Section 1.5, all relative equivalence notions are defined with respect to numerical equivalence classes. So I wonder if a divisor $D$ being 'relative $\sim \sim$ might mean that we can choose a divisor $D^{\prime}$ numerically equivalent to $D$ such that $D^{\prime}$ is transversal to the general (or each) fiber and $D^{\prime}$ is $\sim \sim$ in general (or each) fiber?
